# Correcting a Selector error in iOS Obj.C

Tags: objective-c

I am using iOS 6.1, have a question on an error.

'RegFile' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector.

A white space after RegFile:   ....   RegFile : clears the error but I would like to understand how to fix this. The white space clears the error but negates the method?

[image: white space eliminates error but negats method]

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class FileHandle;

@interface FileHandle : NSObject {
  NSArray *paths;
  NSFileManager *fileManager;
}

- (NSString *)GetSyncFileName;
- (void)CreateBarcodeDirectory;
- (void)ReadRegistry:(NSString *)RegFile :(char *)RegData;  // Whitespace after RegFile clears error but negates the method??
- (void)SaveRegistry:(NSString *)RegFile:(char *)RegData :(NSString *)RegString;
- (NSString *)ReadDataFromFile :(int)path :(NSString *)filename :(char *)data;
- (void)WriteDataToFile :(int)path :(NSString *)filename :(NSString *)data :(NSString *)content;
- (NSArray *)GetFileList :(int)path;
- (NSString *)GetDirectory:(int)path;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *paths;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFileManager *fileManager;
@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Your NSString parameter should have an argument name:

```
-(void)readRegistry:(NSString *) stringName regFile:(char *) regData;
```

Also the name of the method (and all its parts) should start with lower case letters.